# How to export every TikZ image to a separate pdf file?

Tags: pdf-generation, latex, pdflatex, tikz

I'm creating some graphs for my thesis in a single `.tex` file using the TikZ package in LaTeX.
I'm using the standalone document class so that my graphs are generated without whitespaces.

How can I export every graph in a separate PDF file so I can load them individually in another project?

Answer (score 15):

The tikz library *external* does just what you want:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

It will generate one PDF per `tikzpicture`. You can define an output directory with:

```
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./dir/]
```

(Without `/` at the end it simply appends "dir" to the beginning of the output filenames)

Comment: Note that you may need to add the `-shell-escape` flag when compiling. E.g. `pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex`.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile `generate1.tex` file, it will produce `generate1.pdf` file. When you rename the `.tex` file (f.e. `generate2.tex`), new pdf will also have different name (`generate2.pdf`), thus the old pdf won't be deleted.

If you want to display TikZ images only, use `\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}`. If you are interested, you can find the sample code [here](https://www.overleaf.com/2601070wcczqh).

If you want to load them, use [includepdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39443/76839).

Comment: Instead of renaming the .tex file for every image, you could use the `-jobname=...` option when compiling. You can include the pdf files just like other images - no need for the `includepdf` package unless you want them as fullpaper images.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I export every graph in a separate PDF file so I can load them individually in another project?

You don't need to have them as separate PDF files, you can use the `page=...` to select the page with the image you would like to include:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[page=42]{example-image-duck}
\caption{cute duck}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[page=99]{example-image-duck}
\caption{even cuter}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```